# d3.js force layout with some fixed nodes (in a grid)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

Im doing a project using d3 and a force layout
I have roughly 50 nodes, out of which I would like to have 10 of them in a fixed position.
I know how to fix the position and set the coordinates, but Im having issues calculating their position.

What I want is the have the fixed nodes placed in a 2d grid centered around the center of the canvas. So if there is only one fixed node it would be placed in the center of the canvas, if four nodes, they should be placed equally around the center.

I need to use the force layout for the rest of the project, so using something like d3-grid is not an option.
I have looked around the webs, but I have not found anything useful.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly not d3 related issue. You need a 2d positioning algorithm to set the default position of the fixed nodes.

If you have a few nodes, and only a single circle, then you can count the coords by applying simple trigonometry. For example when `0,0` is the center of the circle and `r` is the radius of the circle, then you can divide the circle evenly, and rotate the first node to your favorite position:

- by 1 node

  - `x1 = 0`,
    `y1 = 0`
- by 2 nodes

  - `x1 = r`,
    `y1 = 0`
  - `x2 = r cos(0° + 360°/2) = r`,
    `y2 = r sin(0° + 360°/2) = 0`
- by 3 nodes

  - `x1 = 0`,
    `y1 = r`
  - `x2 = r cos(90° + 360°/3) = -r cos30° = -0.866r`,
    `y2 = r sin(90° + 360°/3) = -r sin30° = -0.5r`
  - `x3 = r cos(90° + 360°2/3) = r cos30° = 0.866r`,
    `y3 = r sin(90° + 360°2/3) = -r sin30°= -0.5r`
- by 4 nodes

  - `x1 = r cos45° = 0.707r`,
    `y1 = r sin45° = 0.707r`
  - `x2 = r cos(45° + 360°/4) = -r sin45° = -0.707r`,
    `y2 = r sin(45° + 360°/4) = r cos45° =  0.707r`
  - `x3 = r cos(45° + 360°2/4) = -0.707r`,
    `y3 = r sin(45° + 360°2/4) = -0.707r`
  - `x4 = r cos(45° + 360°3/4) = 0.707r`,
    `y4 = r sin(45° + 360°3/4) = -0.707r`

and so on... Another way to count the coords is using a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

[image: figure 1]

*figure 1 - divide the circle evenly by 2(green), 3(yellow) and 4(red) nodes*

Over node count 4 you can use a grid:

[image: figure 2]

*figure 2 - a grid with the circle from figure 1*

There are several other approaches, for example you can use any kind of 2d [lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28group%29) or [voronoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) instead of a [grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grid). All you need to copy the code of the positioning part of d3 grid and voronoi layouts. Another option to keep dividing circles with increasing radius depending on the node count, etc...

*off: I think it is way too hard to extend the force layout. I had many problems with it by applying custom forces, so I decided to write my custom layout... :S It would be much better to have a collection of appliable forces so ppl could build custom force layouts much easier. I think I'll create an issue about this...*